# Haskell ghc visual studio DLL weird behaviour

Tags: c++, haskell, visual-studio-2015, ghc, ffi

I am trying to call a C DLL built with visual studio (2015 community edition) from GHC (version 7.8.3) on windows.

C code: (myDLL.cpp)

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int someFn() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Haskell code: (Main.hs)

```
module Main where

import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.C.Types 
import Data.Int

foreign import ccall unsafe "someFn" c_someFn :: CInt
mySomeFn = c_someFn

main :: IO ()
main = do let z = mySomeFn
          print z
```

after copying the generated x64 .dll and .lib and .hs file to the same folder, and running

```
 ghci -L. -lmyDLL Main.hs
 ...
 >main
```

It prints '42' as expected.

Running

```
ghc -L. -lmyDLL Main.hs
```

compiles and links fine, but after executing main.exe, no output is printed. Not even an error message. Why does this happen?

EDIT:
Here's what I did to fix it. Install latest Haskell Platform, then download and copy the latest copy of binutils to the mingw folder of haskell platform. (D:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.2-a\mingw for me). Next, it started complaining about zlib1.dll, so I also downloaded that from MSYS2 and pasted it in the mingw\bin folder. After that, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems similar to [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10885) issue. Basically, `ghc-7.8` distribution contains buggy binutils, they don't handle Visual Studio .lib files properly. The workaround is to upgrade `mingw` distribution or regenerate the .lib file. See the ticket (and also [#10726](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10726)) for details.

Comment: Thanks! Hope they fix this in the next release.

Comment: side question: it looks compiling and running works equally well having only the .dll present, without the .lib file, so is it necessary to include a .lib?

Comment: @user3042966 basically .dll contains everything linker needs. But some linkers are not able to extract that information from .dll, so .lib exists. I don't know all the details though.